# Play encrypted video in android webview

Tags: android, html, webview, android-mediaplayer

> I have specific requirement in android project in which i am
>   downloading some encrypted html5 resources and displaying that html5
>   webview in android  But we are also downloading encrypted video files 
>   My requirement is to decrypt that video file and play it from html5
>   webview

Is there any way in which i can **intercept video playing** , **decrypt that file** and **playing after that**

Regards
Bindal

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193350/how-to-play-an-encrypted-video-file-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294149/play-encrypted-video-by-libmedia-in-android